# Comparing string vectors and quantifying differences

Tags: regex, r, string

Idea is to compare two string vectors such as:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("New York 001", "Orlando 002", "Boston 003", "Chicago 004", "Atlanta 005"),
                 b = c("NEW YORK  001", "Orlando", "Boston (003)", "Chicago 005", "005 Atlanta"))
```

And come up with a way to give them some measure of precision. Basically adding column c that has a numeric value.

My train of thought:

We have this:

```
> df
             a             b
1 New York 001 NEW YORK  001
2  Orlando 002       Orlando
3   Boston 003  Boston (003)
4  Chicago 004   Chicago 005
5  Atlanta 005   005 Atlanta
```

First thing's first - strip whites, ignore cases and remove all special characters while we're at it.

```
df$a <- gsub("[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]", "", toupper(df$a))
df$b <- gsub("[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]", "", toupper(df$b))
```

What we get:

```
> df
           a          b
1 NEWYORK001 NEWYORK001
2 ORLANDO002    ORLANDO
3  BOSTON003  BOSTON003
4 CHICAGO004 CHICAGO005
5 ATLANTA005 005ATLANTA
```

So now we're at the core of the problem.

First line would be 100% match.
Second line has 7 matching characters out of maximum 10 in col a. Hence 70%.
Third now matches at 100%.
Fourth has 90% match.
Fifth one is tricky. Human mind tells me they match, but there's problem with the order. But that's not how the computer works. Realistically it can be measured as 70% match because 7 consecutive characters repeat in both strings.

So the question is:

How to make this quantitative measure of string comparison?

Perhaps there is a better way to do this, since I've never had an experience with comparing string sets on partial match. And comming up with this particular quantifiable measure is just my intuitive way of doing things. 
I wouldn't be surprised if R already had a library/function that does all this in a better way that I'm simply not aware of.

Comment: in you real vector, can we assume that the only thing which is different between the two strings are the numbers? if this is the case you would just have to compare the numbers, which is a lot faster and easier, just strip them out and compare them or calculate the difference

Comment: No, not really. Text strings can be really anything, so general solution is preferable. I was thinking something along the lines of number of consecutively matching [0-9a-zA-Z] divided by longest string.

Comment: yeah, but this requires looping and trying to match, which is slow

Comment: I'm sincerely hoping of some vectorized solution. I'm pretty sure I could write a loop to solve this. Lets say, I want this function efficient. Amount of data to chew through is quite large. And this has various applications and might be of interest to someone else who happens to read this post.

Comment: without making more assumptions I cant think of any other way than looping through increasing parts of a comparing those to b and quitting once they don't match, think hard about the two vectors you want to compare and look for patterns which lead to simplifying the problem, otherwise a loop is your only bet; but of course there are a lot of people out there who are a lot smarter than me, so maybe one of them can come up with a better solution

Comment: the only tweak I can come up with is to do the looping "backwards" beginning with the whole string of a and trying to match, than trying one character less and so on, given that most of the strings match with a high percentage

Comment: Oh my. Well, thanks for input. I'll try to do more research on this, but somehow I'm more than sure that this problem has occured somewhere else and there is a ready tool to do this properly. I will update my progress on this.

Comment: do so, I would also try other languages if it doesn't work in R, python for example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've arrived to fairly easy answer to my own question. And it is Levenshtein distance. Or `adist()` in R.

Long story short:

```
df$c <- 1 - diag(adist(df$a, df$b, fixed = F)) / apply(cbind(nchar(df$a), nchar(df$b)), 1, max)
```

This does the trick.

```
> df
           a          b   c
1 NEWYORK001 NEWYORK001 1.0
2 ORLANDO002    ORLANDO 0.7
3  BOSTON003  BOSTON003 1.0
4 CHICAGO004 CHICAGO005 0.9
5 ATLANTA005 005ATLANTA 0.7
```

Update:

Running the function on one of my data sets returns cute result (that made my inner nerd chuckle a bit):

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1650.7 Gb
```

So, I guess it's another `apply()` loop for `adist()`, taking diagonal of the whole matrix is... well, fairly inefficient.

```
df$c <- 1 - apply(cbind(df$a, df$b),1, function(x) adist(x[1], x[2], fixed = F)) / apply(cbind(nchar(df$a), nchar(df$b)), 1, max)
```

This modification yields very satisfying results.

Answer (score 7):

A more correct answer with Rcpp:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericVector commonChars(CharacterVector x, CharacterVector y) {
  int len = x.size();
  NumericVector out(len);
  double percentage;

  int count=0,k=0;
  std::string compared;
  std::string source;

  for (int i=0; i<len;++i) {
    source = x[i];
    compared = y[i];
    count=0;
    k=0;

    for (int j=0;j<compared.length();j++) {
      if (source[j] == compared[j]) { count++; continue; }

      while(k < source.length()) {
        if (source[j] == compared[k]) { count++; break; }
        k++;
      }
    }
    percentage = (count+0.0)/(source.length()+0.0);
    out[i] = percentage;
  }
  return out;
}')
```

Giving:

```
> commonChars(df$a,df$b)
[1] 1.0 0.7 1.0 0.9 0.7
```

I didn't bench it against other answers nor with large dataframe.

---

Not really what you're wishing but here's an idea (I'll try to improve it):

```
df$r <- gsub("\\w","(\1)?",df$a)
for (i in 1:length(df$a)) {
   df$percentage[i] < ( as.integer( 
                           attr( 
                             regexpr( df$r[i], df$b[i]), 
                             "match.length" 
                           ) 
                       ) / str_length(df$a[i]) * 100) 
}
```

Output:

```
               a          b                                        r percentage
1 NEWYORK001 NEWYORK001 (N)?(E)?(W)?(Y)?(O)?(R)?(K)?(0)?(0)?(1)?        100
2 ORLANDO002    ORLANDO (O)?(R)?(L)?(A)?(N)?(D)?(O)?(0)?(0)?(2)?         70
3  BOSTON003  BOSTON003     (B)?(O)?(S)?(T)?(O)?(N)?(0)?(0)?(3)?        100
4 CHICAGO004 CHICAGO005 (C)?(H)?(I)?(C)?(A)?(G)?(O)?(0)?(0)?(4)?         90
5 ATLANTA005 005ATLANTA (A)?(T)?(L)?(A)?(N)?(T)?(A)?(0)?(0)?(5)?         30
```

Drawbacks:

- There's a for loop
- `ATLANTA005` return 30% because of the 005 matching only in the order.

I'll see if I can find a way to build a better regexp

Comment: This is a valid solution, perhaps lets see where it leads? I'm not sure of how efficient is my own solution. I have an `apply()` loop inside my own solution and `adist()` returns matrix which might grow fairly large and inefficient with larger data sets. There's a need for some benchmarking.

Comment: @A.Val. Added an alternative with Rcpp

Answer (score 4):

Using *stringdist* package, compute Damerau-Levenshtein distance:

```
#data
df <- read.table(text="
a          b
1 NEWYORK001 NEWYORK001
2 ORLANDO002    ORLANDO
3  BOSTON003  BOSTON003
4 CHICAGO004 CHICAGO005
5 ATLANTA005 005ATLANTA",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(stringdist)
cbind(df, lavenshteinDist = stringsim(df$a, df$b))
#            a          b lavenshteinDist
# 1 NEWYORK001 NEWYORK001             1.0
# 2 ORLANDO002    ORLANDO             0.7
# 3  BOSTON003  BOSTON003             1.0
# 4 CHICAGO004 CHICAGO005             0.9
# 5 ATLANTA005 005ATLANTA             0.4
```

**Edit:**
There are many algorithms to quantify string similarities, you need to test it on your data and choose appropriate one. Here is the code to test them all:

```
#let's try all methods! 
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(c("osa", "lv", "dl", "hamming", "lcs", "qgram",
                 "cosine", "jaccard", "jw", "soundex"),
               function(i)
                   cbind(df, Method=i, Dist=stringsim(df$a, df$b,method = i))
               ))
```

Comment: The main drawback I'm seeing is the ATLANTA one, where OP wish to optain 70% and not 40% ... (that's just a sidenote)

Comment: @Tensibai it is about choosing the right string similarity method, for this case "lcs" method gives similar result - `1.0, 0.8, 1.0, 0.9, 0.7`, in my post I used default "osa".